# Function aborts after await

Tags: javascript, promise

In a browser extension I'm trying to:

- find a button
- update its text every second for 10 seconds
- invoke submit

Simple enough, but unfortunately I'm a JavaScript novice.

I'm clueless: Why does the code below not reach line #15 (after await)?

```js
const Timeout = 10000;
const CountdownStep = 1000;

async function scheduleSubmit(node, timeout) {
  originalTextContent = node.textContent;
  while (timeout > 0) {
    console.log(`Timeout: ${timeout}`);
    try {
      await new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`[Promise] Timeout: ${timeout}`);
        node.textContent = `${originalTextContent} (${timeout / 1000})`;
        timeout -= CountdownStep;
        console.log(`[Promise] Timeout: ${timeout}`);
      }, CountdownStep)));
      console.log('Hello? Helloooooooo??');
    } catch (err) {
      log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
  }
  node.submit();
}

scheduleSubmit(document.getElementById('foo'), Timeout);
```

```html
<html><body>
<button type="button" id="foo">Run</button> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: You have to resolve your promise by calling `resolve()`

Comment: Move your `setTimeout`-wrapper-`Promise` to a separate function.

Comment: Protip: it's invariably a bad idea to use `Promise`'s primitives (such as `new Promise`, and especially `.then()`) inside a function that's already `async`. While it _isn't incorrect_, it's often confusing to people who have to read your code. Also, your code has closures nested 3 levels deep, that's enough to make me want to rip them all out and move them to named functions.

Comment: @Dai, thanks, that's good feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract a simple `delay` helper that returns a Promise that resolves after the specified amount of time you code becomes way more readable. Not to speak you can test and debug your code separately to identify the issue.

```js
const SUBMIT_TIMEOUT = 10000;
const COUNT_DOWN_STEP = 1000;

function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout))
}

async function scheduleSubmit(node, timeout) {
  const originalTextContent = node.textContent;
  while (timeout > 0) {
    try {
      await delay(COUNT_DOWN_STEP);
      
      node.textContent = `${originalTextContent} (${timeout / 1000})`;
      timeout -= COUNT_DOWN_STEP;
    } catch (err) {
      log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
  }
  node.submit();
}

scheduleSubmit(document.getElementById('foo'), SUBMIT_TIMEOUT);
```

```html
<html><body>
<button type="button" id="foo">Run</button> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Upvoted for having _much cleaner_ code (thought I'd rename the `const Timeout` and `const CountdownStep` to use the_conventional `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` style as `const SCHEDULE_TIMEOUT` and `const SCHEDULE_COUNTDOWN_STEP`, as it's a bad idea to use such a general name as "Timeout").

Answer (score 1):

You just need to resolve the Promise calling resolve():

```js
const Timeout = 10000;
const CountdownStep = 1000;

async function scheduleSubmit(node, timeout) {
  originalTextContent = node.textContent;
  while (timeout > 0) {
    console.log(`Timeout: ${timeout}`);
    try {
      await new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`[Promise] Timeout: ${timeout}`);
        node.textContent = `${originalTextContent} (${timeout / 1000})`;
        timeout -= CountdownStep;
        console.log(`[Promise] Timeout: ${timeout}`);
        resolve();
      }, CountdownStep)));
      console.log('Hello? Helloooooooo??');
    } catch (err) {
      log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
  }
  node.submit();
}

scheduleSubmit(document.getElementById('foo'), Timeout);
```

```html
<html><body>
<button type="button" id="foo">Run</button> 
</body></html>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Np Glad I could help :)